# How do Fabric get the iOS UDID of a iOS device?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, udid

Fabric use some kind of certificate to get the UDID of the user and send it later to the user via email, anyone have information about the kind of certificate or the process involved to get the UDID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get UDID from device you need to install an .mobileconfig on this device. It works the following way:

1. Users request a .mobileconfig file with proper configuration from your server to his or her iDevice.
2. iOS detects .mobileconfig and opens it in Settings Application.
3. If user allows installation of this profile then iOS returns response with UDID and other information to the URL that is defined in the mobileconfig. Usually this URL points to your web server.

This is the short explanation. You can find full version with file examples & etc here and in the referenced articles:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH4-SW1